# Bootstrap style navbar not hide when scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When the screen width < 768px, I can't figure out why my navbar doesn't scroll although I have set it to `.navbar-static-top`,  it still looks like `.navbar-fixed-top`.

See my Plunker, the code is in file `dashborad.html` line 21

```
<nav class="nav navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse  col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 ">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vlx47gPERIJ8ELGEOWZm?p=preview

And there is `mycss.css` and `main.css` file, I don't know which part of my script cause that probelm.

Comment: I think this behavior is by default in bootstrap.

Comment: The `static-top` can be srolled, see [this demo](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)

Comment: The problem is in your 'main.css'.

Comment: Try to remove `main.css` and import `bootstrap.css` from CDN (you have link in head tag, just uncomment it).

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev Hi, can you find out which part of `main.css` went wrong?

Comment: The problem is in `[ui-view] {}` style  at `Line 7156` in `main.css`

Comment: I commented it out, but it looks the same, would you provide a more detail hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure it has something to do with that `dashboard-page` class, the navbar is trapped inside that div which is always 100% of the screen, so it gives the illusion that the navbar is always fixed on top.

What's the purpose of this class? Is it really necessary?

Remove both `.dashboard-page .main` in line 6997 in `main.css` and `.dashboard-page` class, plan your page differently, the main element doesn't have to be positioned absolute, unless it's a popup or some kind of a div on top of everything. Remove these classes, re-structure your html and you'll be good to go!

Comment: It can be dropped. Would you provide me more detail solution?

Comment: Line 6997 in main.css, remove the class .dashboard-page .main and you'll see that you can scroll and the navbar will remain on top. The thing is your css structure is not correct, you may have used positioning when you didn't have to. You'll have to go deeper and eliminate unneeded positioning, and that's where your problem lays. :)

Comment: I had removed these classes, and delete the `position:absolute` in `.main`, but how to plane my page differently to see it work?

Comment: Not sure you need to actually, once you take these two classes out everything should work properly. Test it in a proper tab and not in plunker, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Once I remove the `dashboard-page` classes, my page doesn't scroll at all, how to solve it?

Comment: Ok I found it, line 7179. Remove overflow: hidden from the html, body and it should work out. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!!! The bounty can't be awarded in 22 hours, I'll give it to you tomorrow.